# Unity Recttransform contains point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to check if Rect transform contains point? Thanks in advance. I tried Bounds.Contains() and RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint() but that didn't help me

```
private bool AreCoordsWithinUiObject(Vector2 coords, GameObject gameObj)
{
    Bounds bounds = gameObj.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;
    return bounds.Contains(new Vector3(coords.x, coords.y, 0));
}
```

This way I have an error "There is no renderer attached to the object" but I've been attached CanvasRenderer to it.

```
RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(gameObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), coords);
```

This method always return false

```
if (AreCoordsWithinUiObject(point, lines[i]))
{
    print("contains");
}
```

lines is a list of GameObjects

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you tried. What you have in your question is simply a function. Put the code that's not working. Both the `Bounds.Contains` and `RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint` and someone might be able to spot your problem.

Comment: I updated the post with code

Comment: Maybe because you are trying to get a "Renderer" and not a "CanvasRenderer"?

Comment: I tried to get CanvasRenderer but it doesn't work

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CanvasRenders don't have a `bounds` member variable. However, your task can be accomplished with just the [RectTransform.rect](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-rect.html) member variable, as we can get both the width and the height of the rectangle in this fashion. My script below assumes your canvas element is anchored to the center of your Canvas. It prints "TRUE" when your mouse is inside of the element the script is attached to.

```
void Update()
{
    // convert pixel coords to canvas coords
    Vector2 point = Input.mousePosition - new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2); 
    Debug.Log(IsPointInRT(point, this.GetComponent<RectTransform>()));
}

bool IsPointInRT(Vector2 point, RectTransform rt)
{
    // Get the rectangular bounding box of your UI element
    Rect rect = rt.rect;

    // Get the left, right, top, and bottom boundaries of the rect
    float leftSide = rt.anchoredPosition.x - rect.width / 2;
    float rightSide = rt.anchoredPosition.x + rect.width / 2;
    float topSide = rt.anchoredPosition.y + rect.height / 2;
    float bottomSide = rt.anchoredPosition.y - rect.height / 2;

    //Debug.Log(leftSide + ", " + rightSide + ", " + topSide + ", " + bottomSide);

    // Check to see if the point is in the calculated bounds
    if (point.x >= leftSide &&
        point.x <= rightSide &&
        point.y >= bottomSide &&
        point.y <= topSide)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me!

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide your UI Camera as third parameter to RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint to make it work correct

Comment: This is the right answer. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint.html

Answer (score 1):

For a UI object `container` you can just use the `Contains` method of its rect with a local position:

```
container.rect.Contains(localPosition);
```

If you prefer working with a world position instead simply convert it to local space:

```
container.rect.Contains(container.InverseTransformPoint(worldPosition));
```